# How to create an Image Without HW Exception Handlers for ARM Cortex M3 using armcc

Tags: build, arm, cortex-m

Basically, I need to create an user application which can be called my simple kernel for ARM Cortex M3. 
Kernel and User application are different uVision Projects for now. 
Kernel handles all HW exceptions (SVC, PendSV, Hardfault etc.)

User application is located in specific address using startup.s file and kernel is able to start this user application within its static address.

On the other hand, startup.s file of user app also includes HW Exception Handler definitions but user application never handle or should not handle hw exceptions. It should be under Kernel responsibility.

Is it possible to disable/ignore/avoid HW Exception handling for a project or build? (Only code, stack and data section addresses should be known when user app is built. )

Comment: I have to ask the obvious question. Have you tried editing the startup.s file of the user app to remove the HW exception handler definitions?

Comment: Use your own startup code for the application and remove the vector table (almost?) altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses. Yes, as you suggested, when I removed vector tables from startup.s it seems work.

In addition, I also replaced main function instead of Reset_Handler, I could located main function as start point. (Kernel already initializes whole system)
While first word shows SP, second shows code start point (main)

My simple startup.s file is now

```
; Vector Table Mapped to Address 0 at Reset

                AREA    RESET, DATA, READONLY
                EXPORT  __Vectors
                IMPORT  __main

__Vectors       DCD     __initial_sp            ; Top of Stack
                DCD     __main                  ; Start Point
```

Thanks.

Comment: Note: This code does not initialize the data segments - but this taks may already be done by the kernel here.